# Asp Mvc 4 action was not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-code-404, url-routing

I'm working on a project in ASP MVC 4. it was working good. but few days ago i had very strange problem.
i have controller "Dashboard" when i call its index as ~/Dashboard/index it works fine but if i call it as ~/Dashboard i got HTTP 404 not found error.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "UI.Web.Controllers" }
            );
```

i even add a route config for Dashboard controller but it doesn't work

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Dashboard",
            url: "Dashboard/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "UI.Web.Controllers" }
            );
```

Same kind of problem in some controllers in my Admin area (some are working fine and some gives HTTP 404 not found error.
My Area route config is:

```
context.MapRoute(
                "DMS_Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Contact", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new string[] { "UI.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
            );
```

in admin area some controller's index action not working and one controller having AddEdit action that also not working.

```
public ActionResult AddEdit(string id)
        {
            var user = new Models.RegisterModel();//string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) ? new Models.RegisterModel() : Membership.GetUser(id);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
            {
                var obj = Membership.GetUser(id);
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    user.Email = obj.Email;
                    user.UserName = obj.UserName;
                }
            }

            ViewBag.PageTitle = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) ? "Add User" : "Edit User";
            ViewBag.IsAjax = Request.IsAjaxRequest();
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Users/AddEditPartial.cshtml", user);
            return View("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Users/AddEdit.cshtml", user);
        }
```

in AddEdit action if i call it as ~/Admin/User/AddEdit/a it works but if i call it as ~/Admin/User/AddEdit it also gives HTTP 404 not found error.

is this behaviour due to some framework update issue or code problem? any idea....
i don't think that this is coding issue because same code was working before......

Now i was about finish my project and in last stage i stuck here.

complete routes.config is look like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Dashboard",
                url: "Dashboard/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new string[] { "UI.Web.Controllers" }
                );

    routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                    namespaces: new[] { "UI.Web.Controllers" }
                );
```

and my AdminAreaRegistration code is:

```
context.MapRoute(
                "DMS_Users",
                "Admin/Users/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Users", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new string[] { "UI.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
            );
context.MapRoute(
                "DMS_Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Contact", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new string[] { "UI.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
            );
```

Comment: The order in which the routes are added matters; please edit your question to show the routes as they appear in your RouteConfig file.

Answer (score 1):

As Tieson T. pointed in comment, the order in which the routes are added matters. The first route matched will be mapped to the handler.

Defining routes can be confusing and difficult to diagnose. I found following tips useful to work with routes:

1. Debugging the routes: You can use a [route debugger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/) as explained [here](http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/debugging-mvc-with-route-debugger-tool.html).
2. Define as less routes as possible in your RouteConfig file.

Once you have more information on which URL is mapped to what route, it is easier to figure out how to adjust the order in `RouteConfig.cs` file. If you still face a problem, share all routes define in the same order and share which URL is having problem.

Comment: route debugger is not working on my machine. when i run site in browser it shows home page. route debegger is also enabled in web.config.
can u please explain in detail how can i make it working or any detail example?

Comment: Have you seen this link http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/debugging-mvc-with-route-debugger-tool.html? I used it once and all i did was to install nuget package.

Comment: @Anjum What errors are you getting with the route debugger? you do have to type in the route in the URL for it to work..

Answer (score 0):

Add default action route:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "DefaultAction",
        url: "{controller}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

For Admin area:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultId",
            url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score -1):

i couldn't find the reason. so for now to finish my project i move all my controllers from Admin area to root. and that works for me. 
but question still there why this happened and how to resolve this.

Comment: If the question hasn't been answered, you should leave it open instead of marking this as the correct answer.